# Filter specific shortcode output?

Tags: filters, shortcode, hooks

Is there a hook in WordPress that I can use to filter the output of a specific shortcode? Something like this:

```
add_filter('shortcode_output', 'my_filter_function', 2);

function my_filter_function ( $output, $shortcode ) {
    ....
}
```

Where `$shortcode` would be something like `[my_schortcode]` or even better, shortcode and its attributes separated into an array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[There is no filter](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/shortcodes.php) that I know of that is meant to target individual shortcodes like you want.

You can filter attributes with [`shortcode_atts_{$shortcode}`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/shortcodes.php#L332) though.

You can hijack another shortcode by creating your own callback and registering it with the original shortcode slug. I think that is what you are probably going to need to do.

Proof of concept:

```
function my_gallery_shortcode($atts) {
  return 'howdy';
}
add_shortcode('gallery','my_gallery_shortcode');
```

Now try to use a gallery :)

Comment: You're right. There is no filter for what I wanted. So instead of that I am filtering `the_content`. It works for my use-case.

Comment: As of v4.7, there is a filter. See [Shawn H's answer below](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/252160/2807).

Answer (score 27):

WordPress 4.7 introduced a new filter, [`do_shortcode_tag`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/32790), to do exactly this.

Comment: +1 for this solution as it now supersedes the accepted answer.  It would be nice if you could edit your answer and give a small example how to use.  The [filter parameters are not obvious](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/38713#file0).

Comment: For completeness' sake: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/do_shortcode_tag/

Comment: More completeness! https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_do_shortcode_tag/

Comment: At last, waited years for this kind of implementation. Wp should always apply this kind of filters before render. An example to remove tabbed indents from the sourcecode:  `function example_shortcode_output($output, $tag, $attr, $m){
 if($tag == 'gallery') $output = str_replace("\t", '', $output);
 return $output;
}
add_filter('do_shortcode_tag', 'example_shortcode_output', 10, 4);`

Answer (score 1):

While there is no hook, there is a small workaround that makes your end-goal possible. You can create a new shortcode that, on a per-instance basis, you always wrap around any other shortcode whose output you want to filter.

Usage in a post, etc:

```
Here is some post text. Blah blah...
[filter][target_annoying_shortcode size="small" limit="20"][/filter] 
Here is some more text in my post. More blah blah...
```

In functions.php:

```
function my_shortcode_output_filter( $attr, $content ) {

    // Express the shortcode into its output
    $content_translated = do_shortcode(trim($content));
    if($shortcode_to_modify == $content || !$content_translated) {
        // Error handling
        return 'There was an error in filtering shortcode: '.$content;  
    }

    // Now modify the output as you like, here...

    $content_translated_and_filtered = $content_translated;

    return $content_translated_and_filtered;
 }
 add_shortcode('filter', 'my_shortcode_output_filter');
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that you can filter is the attributes fo the shortcode:

```
apply_filters( "shortcode_atts_{$shortcode}", $out, $pairs, $atts );
```

Point is, that `$shortcode` is the *third* argument when registering a shortcode. This argument is pretty new and nearly no shortcode uses it, therefore it will fall back to the default - which is a `string` of `''`.

This leads to a funny result:

```
add_filter( 'shortcode_atts_', 'wpse112294_shortcode_atts_cb' );
function wpse112294_shortcode_atts_cb( $out, $pairs, $atts )
{
    // here we need to find a way to uniquely identify a shortcode
    // for which we ain't got a name

    // something that makes the shortcode unique:
    $found = isset( $pairs['foo_attribute_key'] );
    if ( $found )
    {
        // Instantly remove this filter to save processing time:
        remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );

        // do something stunning in here!
    }

    return $out;
}
```

So, ***yes***, with a 90% chance we need to filter the output of every(!) shortcode and try to somehow identify the shortcode by either some default arguments (`$pairs`) or by input arguments (impossible). Then, *finally* we're able to process the output. Are we able to process the string itself? No. This has to be done the way @s_ha_dum showed above.

Answer (score 0):

While @s_ha_dum gave a decent answer, you *can* create a new shortcode for the purpose of filtering an existing shortcode. For example,

```
function filter_function($atts, $content) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
            'att1' => 'val1',
            'att2' => 'val2'
    ), $atts));

    //save shortcode output in $return
    $return = do_shortcode("[existing_shortcode att1='$att1' att2='$att2'".$content."/existing_shortcode]");

    //insert code to modify $return

    echo $return;
}
add_shortcode('new_shortcode','filter_function');
```

note that for the `[embed]` shortcode, you have to use

```
global $wp_embed;
$return = $wp_embed->run_shortcode("[embed ...
```

instead of `do_shortcode`